# can't generate core on Solaris

Tags: solaris, coredump

I'm trying to get the process to generate the core file using abort but unsuccessful.

abtest.c:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("callign abort...\n");
  abort();
  printf(".. shouldn't get here\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
callign abort...
Abort
```

I can however dump a core file using gcore. It's generated in the current directory.

My coreadm output:

```
     global core file pattern:
     global core file content: default
       init core file pattern: core
       init core file content: default
            global core dumps: disabled
       per-process core dumps: enabled
      global setid core dumps: disabled
 per-process setid core dumps: disabled
     global core dump logging: disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that the core files were actually directed to /var/core not the current directory. Not sure why, because coreadm did not indicate that. Also, as mentioned, gcore generated the core file in my current dir.
Anyway since /var/core was not writeable (to me) no core file was generated. Made it writeable and got the core file allright.